# How to save custom fields to DB in Django registrationform?

Tags: django, field

ive been struggling with this particular part for days now, and other posts on this problem dont seem to help me out. 
So I have connected the User model with my own Gebruiker model that has fields like city, postalcode etc. Now I have managed to show them up on the registerform, but they dont seem to work. My second question is about the order of the inputfields, every time they appear in a random order. How can I set up a steady order? 
This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Gebruiker
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
woonplaats = forms.CharField(required=True)
postcode = forms.CharField(required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = {'username','email', 'password1', 'password2',  'first_name', 'last_name', 'woonplaats', 'postcode'}

    def save(self, commit=True):

        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']


        gebruiker = Gebruiker(user=user, woonplaats=self.cleaned_data['woonplaats'], postcode=self.cleaned_data['postcode'])
        gebruiker.save()
        if commit:
            gebruiker.save()
            user.save()

        return user, gebruiker
```

(where woonplaats = place of residence)

Here is a part from views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/aanmelden')
else:
    form = RegistrationForm()

args = {'form' : form}
return render(request, 'aanmelden/reg_form.html', args)
```

Models file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.
class Gebruiker(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)
woonplaats = models.CharField(max_length=100)
postcode = models.CharField(max_length=100,  default="")
email = models.CharField(max_length=100,  default="")




@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    Gebruiker.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
instance.gebruiker.save()
```

Gebruiker part in User:

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/49XyT.jpg)

Comment: As i understand you can save in `user` model, but can't in `Gebruiker`?

Comment: Yes, correct @ZagorodniyOlexiy

Answer (score 0):

You have to create object `Gebruiker`. So, instead of this line:

```
 gebruiker = Gebruiker(user = user, woonplaats = self.cleaned_data['woonplaats'], postcode = self.cleaned_data['postcode'])
 gebruiker.save()
```

change to this:

```
  gebruiker = Gebruiker.objects.create(user = user, woonplaats = self.cleaned_data['woonplaats'], postcode = self.cleaned_data['postcode'])
  gebruiker.save()
```

if `Gebruiker` created already, you have to `get` this object:

```
gebruiker = Gebruiker.objects.get(your_parameter)
gebruiker = Gebruiker(user = user, woonplaats = self.cleaned_data['woonplaats'], postcode = self.cleaned_data['postcode'])
gebruiker.save()
```

And the second answer, about ordering of the fields. As I understand your template looks something like that:

```
{{form}}
```

but you can access to the different fields using this code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   ...
   {{ form.woonplaats }}
   {{ form.postcode }}
   ...
   <input type="submit" alt="register" value="Order" />
</form>
```

In this case you can change the order as you want

**UPDATE:**

```
  gebruiker = Gebruiker.objects.get(user = user)
  gebruiker.woonplaats = self.cleaned_data['woonplaats'], 
  gebruiker.postcode = self.cleaned_data['postcode'])
  gebruiker.save()
```

Comment: what should be in the: '(your_parameter)'? And what do you mean by 'create gebruiker'? The model or the instance the user is creating with the form?

Comment: you have model `Gebruiker`. to create the instance of it you have to use this code `gebruiker = Gebruiker.objects.create(...)`

Comment: but the Gebruiker model is linked to User, as with user I also dont do that objects.create(..)

Comment: the Gebruiker fields are shown in the admin page within the User, at the bottom

Comment: then you have to `get` that `Gebruiker` that you need

Comment: it still doesnt work sir, and the regular User fields like email dont save as well

Comment: done. also added a screenshot of the user page in Django Admin

Comment: could you still help me out? @Zagorodniy

Comment: tonight i will emmulate your code on my home computer and will try to help you